# Как защитить свой hotspot?

Tags: безопасность, wifi, hotspot

При включении точки доступа на телефоне, есть человек, который постоянно взламывает пароль от точки и получает доступ к точке. Я пробовал менять пароль, но каким бы сложным он не был, проходит не много времени до того, как его взломают снова. Как от этого защититься? Можно ли создать whitelist для hotspot и добавить в него адреса своих устройств?  Телефон Redmi note 8 pro.

Comment: Модель гаджета забыли указать

Comment: при создании точки доступа посмотрите на настройки защиты, и так же в самом низу менюшки есть пункт черный список, можно попробовать добавить туда вашего пользователя :)

Comment: Там из настроек только SSID и пароль.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от возможностей Вашего гаджета. Защита WPA2-PSK. В дополнительных настройках "Точки доступа" наверняка должны быть пункты скрытый SSID(у меня при включении- скрыть SSID и отключить WPS) и режим управления Стандартный и Режим белого списка(включаете и добавляете свои устройства)

Comment: У меня Redmi note 8 pro. Там из настроек только SSID и пароль. Защита WPA2-PSK.

Comment: И нет никаких расширенных-дополнительных настроек?

Comment: Нет, нету. Я по крайней мере не нашёл

Comment: Тогда Вам на специализированные форумы по типу 4pda и поиск redmi note 8 pro проблемы настройка точки доступа